# Ruby-on-rails: The webpage is not available error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner to ruby on rails; just doing a simple blog. I did what I think is needed:

(1) added  the page and action under route.rb

> get "/posts/index" => "posts#index", as: :index
>
> get "/posts/new" => "posts#new", as: :new

(2) and created the controller `posts_controller.rb`

(3) and also created the new pages:

- index.html.erb
- new.html.erb

But I got an error saying "The webpage is not available".

What can be the reason of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try just using resources :posts

also...make sure the server is running and look at what the stack trace says when you try to access the route

Comment: Hi, if one of the below answers solved the issue, please mark as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, write 'rails s' (make sure you're in that app's directory)

Then go to 'localhost:3000' in your browser.

That should show you your index page.

Also, you should write `root 'posts#index'` in your routes to establish your root page.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have said: I'd also suggest replacing your individual `get` calls with just one line: `resources :posts`. This adds all the necessary routes for a particular resource. Try typing `rake routes` in your terminal before and after the addition. You'll see that some new routes have become available to access actions in your `posts_controller.rb`, such as create, new, edit, show, update, destroy.

Other than that, the error you got suggests that you haven't turned on your server. `rails s` will do that if you're working locally. If you're using Cloud9 or Nitrous (something I highly suggest for new Rails students), use `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` and `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` respectively.

And don't forget, going to the website's homepage isn't enough. You'd probably have to point your browser to `your-dev-link.com/posts` to show all the posts (index) or `your-dev-link.com/posts/new` to access the new post page (new).

Hope this helps!